# Display (Print) with columns Python

Tags: python

I have below script

```
import itertools
import random

print "a"
print "\n"
def weighted_random(weights):
    number = random.random() * sum(weights.values())
    for k,v in weights.iteritems():
        if number < v:
            break
        number -= v
    return k
weights = {'1': 48,
           '0': 52}
    for i in itertools.count(5):
    print weighted_random(weights)

print "b"
print "\n"
def weighted_random(weights):
    number = random.random() * sum(weights.values())
    for k,v in weights.iteritems():
        if number < v:
            break
        number -= v
    return k
weights = {'1': 53,
           '0': 50}
for i in itertools.count(5):
    print weighted_random(weights)
```

I see the result as

```
a
1
0
1
1
0

b
1
0
0
1
1
```

But, I wanna make it to something like. I know that I could assign a and b into something then use that to display them in two columns but I could not achieve that yet. Need Help!

```
a    b
1    0
0    0
0    1
0    1
1    0
```

Comment: You should probably work with a data structure that is in a form of a table to begin with, for example a dataframe (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

Comment: Why do you define the same `weighted_random` function *twice*?

Comment: I really don't know... I was adding functions and things on the book. I am a beginner! New to python and coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't define the same `weighted_random` function twice.

Then you can call the function and print its result inside the same loop and therefore in two parallel columns.

```
import itertools
import random

def weighted_random(weights):
    number = random.random() * sum(weights.values())
    for k,v in weights.iteritems():
        if number < v:
            break
        number -= v
    return k


weights_a = {'1': 48,
             '0': 52}
weights_b = {'1': 53,
             '0': 50}

print "a", "b"

for i in itertools.count(5):
    print weighted_random(weights_a), weighted_random(weights_a)
```

Comment: Also I doubt that your function is behaving as you expect it, you should recheck that again...

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah, I am a very beginner of Python and I know that there is a lot to change.